# .Net SSL/TLS Passthrough

Tags: c#, ssl, stream

I'm wanting to do a protocol analysis that uses SSL/TLS fortunately I can install my own certificate and the DNS portion won't be an issue. My problem is what do I use to do this. I've considered using paros but it will be more trouble than it's worth. So I thought I could write two C# applications. The first is the pseudo server and the other is the pseudo client. The both have a tcp connection between the two of them that I can then use wireshark on. The problem is, is that I have very little experience with streams. So if anyone could point me to helpful articles or if the code is pretty short a sample would be great. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I'm seeing 2 questions here, An Architectural question about writing a program to intercept SSL/TLS, and another about how to use streams. You should probably figure out what the question you really want to ask is, and ask that.

Comment: @Aren I know how to intercept this protocol using rogue DNS. The question is more so how can I connect two streams such that the in of one is the out of the other and vise versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not terribly hard to Read/Write to/from streams, you can't just connect the streams, you'll need to have your own code to do this. Preferably on it's own thread (or worker process or task or whatever threading concept you need).

```
public void ConnectStreams(Stream inStream, Stream outStream)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;

    while((bytesRead = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != 0)
    {
        outStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        outStream.Flush();
    }
}
```

Basically Streams operate on byte arrays. When we run this line:

```
while((bytesRead = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != 0)
```

We are basically saying, perform `Read` on `inStream`, put the read bytes into `buffer`, at index `0` (in buffer) and read a max of `1024` bytes.

Then we assign the return value into `bytesRead` which is the number of ACTUAL bytes read (between `0` and `1024` in this case) and if that is not equal to 0, continue looping.

Then we simply write it back into the `outStream` with the buffer containing the data, and the number of bytes actually read. We perform a flush to actually force the output out vs. stacking up in an internal buffer.

When the stream reaches the EOF, `.Read` will return 0, the loop will exit and you can continue on. This is how you "Connect" two streams at the most simple level.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. A few questions: Will the while loop invariably remain until the streams have disconnected, in this case when the tcp or ssl stream closes? If I have two threads performing the proxy would it require me to lock the streams?

Comment: I've been working with your code and it works great up until the client needs to be disconnected. I tested it using http, when the web server disconnects no problem but when I disconnect the client it is stuck at stream.read with some unsent data in the buffer.

Comment: Got it working the solution was simply to put while loop into a try catch, could you edit your answer to reflect that.